# Font-Awesome icons not changing color React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, font-awesome

I'm trying to change the color of my FontAwesomeIcon and it stays white.

I've tried using `style={{color: 'lime'}}`, `color="green"`, and adding a class to the icon and styling the class.

```
      <li class="actions">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlay} className="start" style={{ 'color': "lime" }} />
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStop} className="stop" />
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} className="delete" />
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPencilAlt} className="edit" />
      </li>
```

I expect the icon to be a lime color, but it stays white.

I've found out if I change the "fill" in the svg on the html to "lime" it changes color.

Comment: Only if you add inline SVG tag, you could use the fill property to change the color.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently there's a `color` prop for `FontAwesomeIcon` as well. So you can just do this:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlay} className="start" color="lime" />
```

Comment: @Ricky it works on my end, so it's either your code snippet that is incomplete (see [mcve]) or the version that you're using that is different, so please specify that as well.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround, if I target the `path` element with css, and color that it will color the icon.

`.actions svg path { color: lime; }`

Comment: targetting the SVG should be enough

Answer (score 0):

if you set universal set color is white or something else, color changing function won't work

```
<div className="two">
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRightFromBracket}
                 className="colred" /> 
<a href="#logout" style={{color:'red'}}>Logout</a> 
</div>


*{
padding: 0;
margin:0;
box-sizing: border-box;
list-style-type: none;
text-decoration: none;
// color:#fff;
}
```